Combining -て form and -たい form
I have recently learned about the -て form and its usage to write coordinate clauses. Now, the -て clause has no tense per se and it depends on the other clause. For example 晩御飯を食べて寝ます and 晩御飯を食べて寝ました, so the tense is decided conjugating the other verb. I was wondering what happens with the -たい given that it's basically an adjective. So, I may coordinate the adjectives like

その漫画を買いたくて読みたいです。

which - unless there is something ungrammatical should mean I want to buy that manga and read it. Clearly, both in English and in Japanese, the will is referred to both the action of buying and reading, that is I want to buy that manga and I want to to read it. On the other hand, if I thought of the -たい form as a tense, I may be tempted to write

その漫画を買って読みたいです。

How is this different from the previous one? Is either of them more natural?
I'd be grateful if you addressed the following point: is the latter sentence more subject to interpretation? For example that the will of doing is only restricted to reading and the action of buying can be seen as a statement? In other words, can I read it as: I('ll) buy that manga and I want to read it, instead of the interpretation above (I want to buy that manga and I want to to read it.)?

FWIW I find the former bit odd for some reason.

I’m not sure if this is actually accurate, but to me, the first one reads as though wanting to buy the manga is one of the two things you want to do, which is semantically rather odd. I can’t even think of a way to phrase it unambiguously and comprehensibly in English, but it feels like you’re saying (with brackets to disambiguate), “I want [to want to buy that manga] and [to read it]” (i.e., you want two things: (1) to want to buy this manga; (2) to read it). “I am desirous of wanting to buy this manga, and of reading it”, perhaps, if we’re feeling Victorian.

@JanusBahsJacquet I was thinking of an awkward enough English rendition last night. After reading the answer below and looking it up more accurately on my grammar book, I understood that, as Zorf said, the -たい and any other derivational suffix distributes over the -て form, not just the tense. And, incidentally that also holds for たり～たり as well.

“〜たい” is typically not repeated and distributes over both clauses. “その漫画を買って読みたい” is typically construed as “I want to buy that comic book and then read it.”.
In fact “〜たくて” is sort of a collocation I guess. It's very often used to mean “because [I] want to” as in “したくてしたわけじゃないから許すよ。” can be used to mean “It's not like you did it willingly so I'll let it slide.” It's commonly used with a repeated verb to basically mean “because [I] want to” or “willingly” with the main verb not being in the “〜たい” form.
derivational suffixes generally distribute their meaning over the “〜て” form, not just conjugational ones. This also applies to say “〜そう” and even say the passive or causative voice. One would generally say “食べて飲ませる” to mean “I make him eat and drink”. The first element is not generally put into the causative as well to express this.

Alright, thanks to your answer and a paragraph in one of my books, I managed to understand that not just the tense but also "derivational suffixes generally distribute their meaning over the “〜て” form". I still have one doubt about the body of your answer, that is what you mean by "sort of a collocation". Let me rephrase it more simply to see if I understand. 〜たくて can be used sometimes, if my intention is to have the "want" part only in the subordinate. For example (using it as a motivation):
食べたくてうちに返えります。 (Since I want to eat, I go home). How does that sound? Is that what you meant?

@Mr.Feynman a “collocation” basically means a fixed pattern that occurs more often together than would normally be statistically expected from it's constitutent parts, but yes, your example sentence, except that it should be “帰ります” is generally how one would use “〜たくて” yes. When “〜たくて” occurs outside of other collocations such as “〜たくて仕方ない” [want it really badly] it almost always indicates that one does something for a reason of wanting something.
